# slide a panel over the content

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a menu(panel) and when I expand a collapsible menu within a layout it compresses the content of the panel next to it. How to expand it over the content? Here my menu code.

```
Ext.define('*****.view.main.MainMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.main.MainMenu',

    title: 'Menu',
    collapsed: true,
    dock: 'left',
    minWidth: 140,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;  

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            collapseDirection: 'left',
            collapsible: true,

            titleAlign: 'center',
            titleCollapse: false,
            items: [
                {

                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it floating, you can change it into a window (which is a specialized panel that is resizeable and floatingby default), you can change the layout of the parent container, you can wrap these two panels into a tabpanel to show one panel at a time, accordion might work for you as well if you need to see only one at a time.  Check out examples from Sencha website to see different combinations.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried to use floating - not working( can't find some example in sencha for my problem(( If you know something else,please give information. Solution with tab panel - for me it's not good idea( I've heard some solution with border layout - border bad for me(

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.define('MainMenu', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

        title: 'Menu',
        collapsed: true,
        titleCollapse: false,
        hideCollapseTool: true,
        minWidth: 140,
        region: 'west'
    });

    var menu = Ext.create('MainMenu');

    var otherPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Other Panel',
        region: 'center'
    });

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        height: 300,
        width: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'border',
        items: [
            menu,
            otherPanel
        ]
    });
});
```